# Differences of the usage of the Square brackets [ ] beetwen "As String" and "As [String]"?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, square-bracket

Someone can explain me which are the differences between using the Square brackets [ ] as this:

```
Private Function FindItem([ListView] As [ListView], [ColumnIndex] As [Int32], [SearchString] As [String], Optional [IgnoreCase] As [Boolean] = False) As Boolean
```

...And this else:

```
Private Function FindItem(ListView As ListView, ColumnIndex As Integer, SearchString As String, Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As Boolean
```

Both works with the same passed arguments.

Where I can learn about this strange vb.net operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords as variables. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwx24eb6.aspx)

I don't believe in using them, just name your variables something meaningful.

```
Dim _name As String ' better choice - has meaning now.
```

Comment: Would it be correct to say that if the thing inside the square brackets is not actually a keyword, then the brackets have no effect?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, there is no difference. The brackets are used to allow the use of reserved words.

Example :

```
Dim [String] As String = Nothing
[String] = "My String has a poor name"
```

The [] around the names allows you to use a reserved word.